# Empty $_ GET after parameter was successfully passed using URL

Tags: php, get

I'm passing a request_id parameter from request.php to offer.php using a URL but while the value of the request_ id shows up in the URL of offer.php, $GET['request_id'] remains undefined.

The code in request.php generating the URL:

```
if (!isset($_GET['category_id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE category_id='$category' ";
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE category_id = '" . 
     $_GET['category_id'] . "'";
}
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($data)>0){
   echo '<table>';  
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
      echo '<tr><td><a href="offer.php?request_id=' . $row['request_id'] . 
       '">Make Offer</a></td></tr>';
```

The code in offer.php where $_GET['request_id'] is undefined:

```
<?php
 $request_id = $_GET['request_id'];
 $asking_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['asking_price']));
?>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo 
  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo MM_MAXFILESIZE; 
  ?>" />
   <fieldset>
     <legend>Make an Offer</legend>
     <label for="ask_price">Asking Price:</label>
     <input type="text"  name="asking_price" /><br />
     <label for="comment">Comments</label>
     <textarea name="comment" /></textarea><br />
     <input type="hidden" name="old_picture" value="<?php if 
      (!empty($old_picture)) echo $old_picture; ?>" />
     <label for="itempicture">Picture of Item</label>
     <input type="file"  name="new_picture" />
   </fieldset>
     <input type="submit" value="Make Offer" name="submit" />
     <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="' . 
      $request_id . '" />';?>    
 </form>
```

The URL of offer.php:
  http://localhost/offer.php?request_id=12

I want to be able to retrieve the value of request_id in the offer.php URL

Comment: Is it a typo in your question here that your `$request_id = $_GET['request_id'];` isn't wrapped in php tags?

Comment: it's wrapped in php tags in the faulty code, just didn't copy the tags, sorry.

Comment: Could you please edit your question so that the code matches your actual code? Makes it easier to help you.

Comment: it's identical now. Unless you need the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect offer.php to have `$_GET[request_id]` populated when reached from the link in `request.php`. (I would also expect an undefined on the `$asking_price =` line because there is no `$_POST['asking_price']`.

I would expect offer.php to give "Undefined $_GET['request_id']" when reached by the submit button in offer.php.

The request from offer.php submit action will be a post request to offer.php based on the form attributes.

If you want to send the request_id in the query string from the submit button in offer.php, you could construct the action attribute like this:
`action="<?php echo  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?request_id=".$_GET['request_id']; ?>">` so that the query string is sent with the post request.

You might consider adding an `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {} else {}` block so the variables can be set appropriately, based on the request method.

Comment: Yes it is, but the request id in the URL should be stored in the $request_id variable and sent to the server with the rest of the data using $_POST

Comment: As of now, $_GET seems not to be grabbing the data from the URL

Comment: Does it depend on whether the link in the `<td>` is clicked or the submit button?

Comment: It should depend on the link in the <td>. But that part seems to be doing its job because when clicked the URL of offer.php looks like this "localhost/offer.php?request_id=12". The value of request_id changes depending on which link is clicked.

Comment: Does the form action send a query string? Answer edit FWIW.

Comment: Yes it does, but the problem is this line "$request_id = $_GET['request_id'];". Why is $request_id throwing up an undefined index error when its value should have been  stored in $_GET['request_id']  since the URL clearly holds the value

Comment: Answer rewritten based on my understanding of the problem.